# Mongoose Population not returning all fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have:
**UserSchema**:

```js
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    image: {
        type: String,
        default: "http://via.placeholder.com/250x200"
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Email missing."],
        unique: true
    },
    kind: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["Admin", "Teacher", "Student"],
        default: "Student"
    },
    isAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    isPromote: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Username missing."],
        unique: true
    },
    password: String
}, options);

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

**StudentSchema**:

```js
var options = {discriminatorKey: 'kind'};
var StudentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    indexNumber: String,
}, options);

module.exports = User.discriminator("Student", StudentSchema);
```

**CourseSchema**:

```js
var CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    code: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    name: String,
    description: String,
    image: {
        type: String,
        default: "http://via.placeholder.com/250x200"
    },
    data: [{
        title: String,
        content: String
    }],
    teachers: [{

            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Teacher"

    }],
    students: [{
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Student"
        },
        entryDate: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    }]
});
```

In my DB, I have following **students** (using MongoDB Compass to show this):
[image: 2 Student Documents]

Also, I have this **teacher**:
[image: Teacher Document]

And this **Course**:

[image: Course Document]

Now on Course show page, I would like to get students enrolled and teachers. I go like this:

```js
Course.findById(req.params.id)
.populate("students.id")
.populate("teachers")
.exec( function(err, foundCourse) {...}
```

I only get this:

```js
students: [
  { _id: 59dbd1259df328279cd5d588, entryDate: 2017-10-12T22:29:48.297Z },
  { _id: 59dc07088c6fd636188d87c5, entryDate: 2017-10-12T22:29:48.297Z }
],
teachers: [
  { _id: 59dbc34832b0041b44a7f648, isPromote: false, isAdmin: false, kind: 'Teacher', image: 'http://via.placeholder.com/250x200' }
]
```

Notice here that:

- For students I am only getting back ref _ids, no populated fields.
- For teachers I am not getting some fields, like firstName, lastName, username etc (Teacher is also discriminator on User)

What I'm expecting from that populate query is to get all fields, for example, students[0] should look like this:

```js
{ _id: 59dbd1259df328279cd5d588, isPromote: false, isAdmin: false, kind: 'Student', image: 'http://via.placeholder.com/250x200', firstName: 'ss', lastName: 'ss', username: 'ss', entryDate: 2017-10-12T22:29:48.297Z }
```

Can anyone tell me how to get those fields, how to populate the right way?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Rather than posting variations on the same question [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700283/populate-doesnt-return-all-fields) and [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46656807/mongoose-populate-doesnt-populate), the general concept is to discover the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46719925/edit) link on your question and make revisions. Particularly when you see comments that ask you to do that. Noting that what you were actually previously asked to show "both" the related schema **and** the data that you believe relates.

Comment: Sorry, but I am new here, still learning how to properly ask questions, and I am stuck on this project for few days now because I can't resolve it, and no answers yet :(

Comment: And you are not going to get an answer until you can provide a case that can actually be reproduced. Which means we need to see your "data" as you have been asked before and still have not done. So can you please include some related data and the result you are expecting. This allows your issue to be **reproduced** and provides what is necessary to actually provide a **working solution**. Try to understand we are not sitting at your desk. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for pointers on how you ask a question like this.

Comment: And please remove your previous questions. This is the same question, just finally embellished, but still missing necessary details. There are no accepted or upvoted answers to previous questions so it is okay for you to delete them.

Comment: Are these changes enough or do I need to add more?

Comment: Missed your response in other messages. You really should not use `id` in schemas. Mongoose considers it to be an alias for `_id`, so you actually should have that in your `students` array definition instead.  Also `.populate({ path: 'students._id teachers' })` is a bit more brief. Note that your data differs on the `students` array which appears to be simple an array of `ObjectId`. Which means your claimed results are not true, nor would the path to `students._id` match anything. Fix the schema and check and fix the data where required.